# SQL: select max values from two related tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, subquery, rank

I have tables: `Waiter` and `WaiterDetail` and `Cafe`. Cafe can have many Waiters and Waiter may have many WaiterDetails. I would like to find oldest WaiterDetail by field CreatedDate, of the first hired Waiter by his HiredDate.

```
Cafe:
     *CafeId(primary)

Waiter:  
     *WaiterId(primary)
     *CafeId
     *HiredDate

WaiterDetail:
     *WaiterDetailID(primary)
     *WaiterId
     *CreatedDate
```

How will look like query for `Oracle` and `MS SQL Server`?

Comment: looks like homework ?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: why would you require it for sql-server and oracle at the same time?

Comment: @Tanner, I have both on the project and I thought about using `dense_rank first order by CreatedDate desc` and not sure it works the same for ms sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have it correct, you want: for each Cafe to find Waiter with the first (earliest) `HiredDate` and, for that waiter, find detail with the oldest (earliest) `CreatedDate`. So, for Oracle (and maybe SQL Server), something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT w.*,
         d.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CafeID
                             ORDER BY w.HiredDate ASC,
                                      d.CreatedDate ASC ) AS rn
  FROM   Waiter w
         INNER JOIN WaiterDetail d
         ON ( w.WaiterId = d.WaiterId )
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```